# How do i use jquery function to more than one div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to have a show/hide function for a `<div>`, using JavaScript/DOM properties.

Using JavaScript `onclick()` with two buttons, `show` and `hide`, each in their own `<div>`s, it would work something like this:

- By default, the `show` button is hidden, the main `<div>` and hide button are displayed. Clicking the `hide` button hides the main `<div>` and 'hide' button itself, displays the `show` button.
- Clicking the `show` button shows the main `<div>` and 'show' button displays the `hide` button I think this can be achieved using something like `document.getElementById(DIVid).style.visibility="hidden"`.

But how do I do this?

Comment: Provide your HTML so that we can understand the structure

Comment: you should create a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#hidebutton').click(function() {
   $('#DIVid, #showbutton').show();
   $(this).hide();
});

$('#showbutton').click(function() {
   $('#DIVid, #hidebutton').show();
   $(this).hide();
});
```

Or if you want:

```
$('#hidebutton, #showbutton').click(function() {
    var show = $(this).is('#showbutton');
    $('#DIVid, #hidebutton').toggle(show);
    $('#showbutton').toggle(!show);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a class to each of that `<div>` and make jQuery function of it. This is sample code:

```
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a"></div>

Jquery code

$(".a").click(function(e){
your code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this: [see Demo](http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp8j)

```
$("#btnclk").click(function() {
    if ($('.test').is(':visible')) {
        $(".test").hide();
    } else {
        $(".test").show();
    }
});

<div class="test">
  Div1
</div>
<div class="test">
  Div1
</div>

<input type="button" id="btnclk" value="Show/Hide">
```

or, if you want to do it with JavaScript, then use `getElementsByClassName` instead of `getElementById`.

Answer (score 0):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/ivayoy/1/edit)*

simple jQuery:

```
$('.show_hide').click(function(){
  $(this).text( $(this).text()==='HIDE'?'SHOW':'HIDE' );
  $(this).next('.box_content').stop().slideToggle();
});
```

HTML:

```
  <div class="box">
    <h2>Title 1</h2><button class="show_hide">HIDE</button>
    <div class="box_content">
      <p>
        1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi tempus tortor at nisl dictum lobortis. Mauris dolor augue, porttitor non cursus et, hendrerit sed mi. Morbi sollicitudin sodales dui, et interdum justo condimentum vel.
      </p>
      
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.box{
  position:relative;
  padding:15px;
  background:#eee;
  margin:10px;
}
.box h2{
  margin:0px;
  padding:5px;
}
.show_hide{
  position:absolute;
  right:15px;
  top:20px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```